# How does SKTexture caching and reuse work in SpriteKit?

Tags: sprite-kit, sktexture, sktextureatlas

It is often mentioned on StackOverflow that SpriteKit does its own
internal caching and reuse.

- [Does Sprite Kit load a texture atlas multiple times if I use SKTextureAtlas later?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20889211)
- [should I cache textures in properties in sprite kit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28007839)
- [SpriteKit memory management preload cached and fps issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21098880)

If I don't make any effort to reuse textures or atlases, what caching
and reuse behavior can I expect from SpriteKit?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Texture Caching in SpriteKit

[“Long story short: rely on Sprite Kit to do the right thing for
you.”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20892648) -@LearnCocos2D

Here’s the long story, as of iOS 9.

The texture’s bulky image data is not kept directly on the `SKTexture`
object.  (See the [`SKTexture` class
reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKTexture_Ref).)

- `SKTexture` defers loading data until necessary.  Creating a
  texture, even from a large image file, is quick and consumes little
  memory.
- Data for a texture is loaded from disk usually when a corresponding
  sprite node is created.  (Or really, whenever the data is needed,
  for example when the `size` method is called).
- Data for a texture is prepared for rendering during the (first)
  render pass.

SpriteKit has some built-in caching for the texture’s bulky image
data.  Two features:

1. The texture’s bulky image data is cached by SpriteKit until
   SpriteKit feels like getting rid of it.

   - According to the `SKTexture` class reference: “Once the SKTexture
     object is ready for rendering, it stays ready until all strong
     references to the texture object are removed.”
   - In current iOS, it tends to stick around longer, perhaps even
     after the whole scene is gone.  [A StackOverflow
     comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21541819) quotes an Apple
     tech support: “iOS releases the memory cached by
     +textureWithImageNamed: or +imageNamed: when it sees fit, for
     instance when it detects a low-memory condition.”
   - In the simulator, running a test project, I was able to see
     texture memory reclaimed immediately after a `removeFromParent`.
     Running on a physical device, though, the memory seemed to
     linger; repeatedly rendering and deallocating the texture
     resulted in no additional disk accesses.
   - I wonder: Could the rendering memory be released early in some
     memory-critical situations (when the texture is retained but not
     currently displayed)?
2. SpriteKit reuses the cached bulky image data smartly.

   - In my experiments, it was hard **not** to reuse it.
   - Say you’ve got a texture displaying in a sprite node, but rather
     than reusing the `SKTexture` object, you call `[SKTexture
     textureWithImageNamed:]` for the same image name.  The texture
     will not be pointer-identical to the original texture, but it
     will share the bulky image data.
   - The above is true whether the image file is part of an atlas or
     not.
   - The above is true whether the original texture was loaded using
     `[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:]` or using `[SKTextureAtlas
     textureNamed:]`.
   - Another example: Let’s say you create a texture atlas object
     using `[SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:]`.  You take one of its
     textures using `textureNamed:`, and you don’t retain the atlas.
     You display the texture in a sprite node (and so the texture is
     retained strongly in your app), but you don’t bother tracking
     that particular `SKTexture` in a cache.  Then you do all of that
     over again: new texture atlas, new texture, new node.  All of
     these objects will be freshly allocated, but they are relatively
     lightweight.  Meanwhile, and importantly: the bulky image data
     originally loaded will be transparently shared between instances.
   - Try this one: You load a monsters atlas by name, and then take
     one of its orc textures and render it in an orc sprite node.
     Then, the player returns to home screen.  You encode the orc node
     during application state preservation, and then decode it during
     application state restoration.  (When it encodes, it doesn’t
     encode its binary data; it encodes its name instead.)  In the
     restored app, you create another orc (with new atlas, texture,
     and node).  Will this new orc share its bulky orc data with the
     decoded orc?  Yes.  Yes it orcking will.
   - Pretty much the only way to get a texture **not** to reuse
     texture image data is to initialize it using `[SKTexture
     textureWithImage:]`.  Sure, maybe `UIImage` will do its own
     internal caching of the image file, but either way, `SKTexture`
     takes charge of the data, and will not reuse the render data
     elsewhere.
   - In short: If you’ve got two of the same sprite showing in your
     game at the same time, it’s a fair bet they are using memory
     efficiently.

Put those two points together: SpriteKit has a built-in cache that
persists the important bulky image data and reuses it smartly.

In other words, it just works.

No promises.  In the simulator running a test app, I can easily prove
that SpriteKit is deleting my texture data from cache before I’m
really done with it.

During prototyping, though, you might be surprised to find reasonably
good behavior from your app even if you never reuse a single atlas or
texture.

## SpriteKit Has Atlas Caching Too

SpriteKit has a caching mechanism specifically for texture atlases.
It works like this:

- You call `[SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:]` to load a texture atlas.
  (As mentioned before, this doesn’t yet load the bulky image data.)
- You retain the atlas strongly somewhere in your app.
- Later, if you call `[SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:]` with the same
  atlas name, the object returned will be pointer-identical to the
  retained atlas.  Textures extracted from the atlas using
  `textureNamed:`, then, will be pointer-identical, too.  (Update:
  The textures will not necessarily be pointer-identical under iOS10.)

Texture objects, it should be mentioned, do not retain their atlases.

## You Might Still Want To Build Your Own Cache

So I see you are building your own caching and reuse mechanisms
anyway.  Why are you doing it?

- Ultimately you have better information about when to keep or purge
  certain textures.
- You might need complete control over the load timing.  For
  instance, if you want your textures to appear instantly when first
  rendered, you’ll use the `preload` methods from `SKTexture` and
  `SKTextureAtlas`.  In that case, you should retain the references
  to the preloaded textures or atlases, right?  Or, will SpriteKit
  cache them for you regardless?  Unclear.  A custom atlas or texture
  cache is a good way to keep complete control.
- At a certain point of optimization (*heaven forbid prematurely!!*),
  it makes sense to stop creating new `SKTexture` and/or
  `SKTextureAtlas` objects over and over, no matter how lightweight.
  Probably you’d build the atlas-reuse mechanism first, since atlases
  are less lightweight (they have a dictionary of textures, after
  all).  Later you might build a separate texture caching mechanism
  for reuse of non-atlas `SKTexture` objects.  Or maybe you’d never
  get around to that second one.  You are busy, after all, and the
  kitchen isn’t cleaning itself, dammit.

All that said, your caching and reuse behavior will probably end up
eerily similar to SpriteKit’s.

How does SpriteKit’s texture caching affect your own texture cache
design?  Here are the things (from above) to keep in mind:

- You can’t directly control the timing of the release of bulky image
  data when using named textures.  You release your references, and
  SpriteKit releases the memory when it wants to.
- You **can** control the timing of the loading of bulky image data,
  using the `preload` methods.
- If you rely on SpriteKit’s internal caching, then your atlas cache
  needs only **retain** references to the `SKTextureAtlas` objects,
  not return them.  The atlas object will automatically be reused
  throughout your app.
- Similarly, your texture cache needs only **retain** references to
  the `SKTexture` objects, not return them.  The bulky image data
  will be automatically reused throughout your app.  (This one weirds
  me out a bit, though; it’s a pain to verify good behavior.)
- Given the last two points, consider design alternatives to a
  singleton cache object.  Instead, you could retain in-use atlases
  on your sprite objects or their controllers.  For the lifetime of
  the controller, then, any calls in your app to `atlasNamed:` will
  reuse the pointer-identical atlas.
- Two pointer-identical `SKTexture` objects share the same memory,
  yes, but due to SpriteKit caching, the converse isn’t necessarily
  true.  If you’re debugging memory problems and find two `SKTexture`
  objects that you expected to be pointer-identical, but aren’t, they
  still might be sharing their bulky image data.

## Testing

I’m a tools novice, so I just measured overall app memory usage on a
release build using the Allocations instrument.

I found that “All Heap & Anonymous VM” would alternate between two
stable values on sequential runs.  I ran each test a few times and
used the lowest memory value as the result.

For my testing I’ve got two different atlases with two images each;
call the atlases A and B and the images 1 and 2.  The source images
are largish (one 760 KiB, one 950 KiB).

Atlases are loaded using `[SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:]`.  Textures are
loaded using `[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:]`.  In the table
below, *load* really means “putting in a sprite node and rendering.”

```
 All Heap
& Anon VM
    (MiB)  Test
---------  ------------------------------------------------------

   106.67  baseline
   106.67  preload atlases but no nodes

   110.81  load A1
   110.81  load A1 and reuse in different two sprite nodes
   110.81  load A1 with retained atlas
   110.81  load A1,A1
   110.81  load A1,A1 with retained atlas
   110.81  load A1,A2
   110.81  load A1,A2 with retained atlas
   110.81  load A1 two different ways*
   110.81  load A1 two different ways* with retained atlas
   110.81  load A1 or A2 randomly on each tap
   110.81  load A1 or A2 randomly on each tap with retained atlas

   114.87  load A1,B1
   114.87  load A1,A2,B1,B2
   114.87  load A1,A2,B1,B2 with preload atlases

* Load A1 two different ways: Once using [SKTexture
  textureWithImageNamed:] and once using [SKTextureAtlas
  textureNamed:].
```

## Internal Structure

While investigating I discovered some true facts about the internal
structure of texture and atlas objects in SpriteKit.

Interesting?  That depends on what kinds of things interest you!

### Structure of a Texture From an `SKTextureAtlas`

When an atlas is loaded by `[SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:]`, inspection
of its textures at runtime shows some reuse.

- During Xcode build, a script compiles the atlas from individual
  image files into a number of large sprite sheet images (limited by
  size, and grouped by @1x @2x @3x resolution).  Each texture in the
  atlas refers to its sprite sheet image by bundle path, stored in
  `_imgName` (with `_isPath` set true).
- Each texture in the atlas is individually identified by its
  `_subTextureName`, and has a `textureRect` inset into its sprite
  sheet.
- All textures in the atlas that share the same sprite sheet image
  will have identical non-nil ivars `_originalTexture` and
  `_textureCache`.
- The shared `_originalTexture`, itself an `SKTexture` object,
  presumably represents the whole sprite sheet image.  It has no
  `_subTextureName` of its own, and its `textureRect` is `(0, 0, 1,
  1)`.

If the atlas is released from memory and then reloaded, the new copy
will have different `SKTexture` objects, different `_originalTexture`
objects, and different `_textureCache` objects.  From what I could
see, only the `_imgName` (that is, the actual image file) connects the
new atlas to the old atlas.

### Structure of a Texture Not From an `SKTextureAtlas`

When a texture is loaded using `[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:]`,
it may come from an atlas, but it doesn’t seem to come from an
`SKTextureAtlas`.

A texture loaded this way has differences from the above:

- It has a short `_imgName`, like “giraffe.png”, and `_isPath` is set
  false.
- It has an unset `_originalTexture`.
- It has (apparently) its own `_textureCache`.

Two `SKTexture` objects loaded by `textureWithImageNamed:` (with the
same image name) have nothing notable in common other than `_imgName.`

Nevertheless, as thoroughly belabored above, this kind of texture
configuration shares bulky image data with the other kind of texture
configuration.  This implies that caching is done close to the actual
image file.

Comment: Bravo. This is super helpful.