# Swift SpriteKit Textures

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, textures

Non-functional code:

```
 if sprite.texture == "texture" {
 (code)
}
```

I'm trying to access the texture of the sprite to run code when the sprite has a specific texture. Currently the texture is only in my Assets hence the parentheses. Can anyone figure out how to rewrite this code in a way that will work?

Comment: That's not a good design.  Use userData with each sprite instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the filename of an SKSpriteNode in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272365/getting-the-filename-of-an-skspritenode-in-swift-3)

Comment: I voted to close due to it answering your question, but in reality, I agree with El Tomato,  redesign your approach to solve this problem better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sprite.texture` is of type `SKTexture?`, so you can't compare it against a string, but should rather compare against an actual SKTexture object.

Nevertheless, you should try to redesign your code, as suggested by others in the comments on your question. Checking against a texture itself is not good design. For one thing, if you decide to use a different texture for your sprites in 2 months, then you will need to remember to revisit this code.

I would suggest subclassing from SKSpriteNode and checking if a sprite's type is the same as your subclass. Other alterantives are to compare the `sprite.name` or the sprite's `userData`.